# Need bindings equivalent of String.replaceAll(...)

Tags: java, javafx

I need to create a binding that allows me to do the equivalent of `String.replaceAll(...)` but with bindings. I have a string, "${driver} driving ${name}", and I want the keys, "${driver}", etc. to be replaced with the specific property. I also want the returned property to be able to add listeners so when `driverProperty` or another changes, the returned property value will change without having to re-call getString().

```
public String getString(Derby derby) {
        String ret;
        if (driverProperty.get().equals("") && nameProperty.get().equals("") && numberProperty.get().equals("") && groupProperty.get().equals("")) {
            ret = "[blank]";
        } else {
            ret = (String) derby.getSettings().get("general.cardisplay").getValue();
            ret = ret.replace("${driver}", driverProperty.get());
            ret = ret.replace("${name}", nameProperty.get());
            ret = ret.replace("${number}", numberProperty.get());
            ret = ret.replace("${group}", groupProperty.get());
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: So? please what you have tried?

Comment: Well I looked at the Javadocs and was unable to find anything other than concat(), which I am pretty sure just adds the strings together. I think there might be something I can do with making custom bindings, but I am unsure where to start.

Comment: Can you at least show a little context? It's not clear what you mean. If you have a `StringProperty` you can just set it to the new value, for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Bindings.createStringBinding()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createStringBinding-java.util.concurrent.Callable-javafx.beans.Observable...-). This takes a function supplying the `String` and a list of values to observe; if any of those values change the binding is marked as invalid.

Your question isn't too clear to me, but I think you can do something like

```
StringBinding formattedString = Bindings.createStringBinding(
    () -> getString(derby), 
    derby.settingsProperty(), 
    nameProperty, numberProperty, 
    driverProperty, groupProperty);
```

Now you can do things like

```
formattedString.addListener((obs, oldFormattedString, newFormattedString) -> {
    // invoked any time the formatted string changes...
});
```

or

```
Label label = new Label();
label.textProperty().bind(formattedString);
```